# /media directory became root owned after upgrade to 21.10

Tags: permissions

I upgraded my Ubuntu to 21.10 yesterday but now I've noticed that when I try to go into  /media/My Passport , I get "Permission Denied". I think this is because my directory became owned by root during the upgrade process. Or, if it always owned by root and never changed, then I was atleast able to cd into it previously. Unfortunately, now, I get:

/media/markleeds> cd 'My Passport'

bash: cd: My Passport: Permission denied

Is there a way to change the directory so that it's not root and just owned by me
like 'My Passport1' is below. Thanks.

drwxrwxrwx 1 markleeds markleeds 4096 Sep  9  2020 'My Passport1'/

Comment: Did you connect 'My Passport' to a Windows computer, with Fast Startup, or did you unplug it from Windows or Ubuntu without unmounting all partitions? In that case the file system in 'My Passport' might be dirty or damaged. - What file system is it - A Linux file system or a Microsoft file system? Check/repair it from the operating system that it belongs to.

Comment: /media has always been owned by root. What other user should own it? It is more relevant to the problem to find out the ownership of things under /media/.

Comment: Always include both the command and the output in your question. Format terminal output as code. Then, you refer to "My Passport" but then list output for "My Passport1". Anyway, you could try removing the USB drive, then deleting any "Passport*" directory that remains (will need to be root). After that, the drive may connect properly when you insert it. That, after following the tip of sudodus: check the file system before attempting anything else.

Comment: Thanks to all. I was doing something dopey because I was looking at a directory that was not the portable usb that was plugged into my machine that I thought I was looking at.  If I should delete this question, please let me know and I apologize for the mistake and the waste of all of your time.